# It seems that jQuery ID selector does not allow ".' . What is the reason ? What can be a work around?

Tags: jquery

I have observed that

```
$("#bank1.bankName").hide();
```

does not work  while

```
$("test").hide()
```

works

What is the reason for that ? What can be a possible work around

**Edited to include markup**

```
<td id = "bank1.bankName">
 <form:input path="bankDetails[0].bankName" size = "12"/>
 </td>
```

I am using Spring MVC

Comment: think of id's and names like using variable names in a programming language. Try to stick with alpha, numeric, and underscore

Answer (score 6):

The problem is because `.` is used to signify a class selector. Your current code is making jQuery search for an element with both the id `bank1` *and* the class `bankName`.

To avoid this, you need to escape the `.` character with `\\`:

```
$("#bank1\\.bankName").hide();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/LDUTv/)

The best course of action is to not use the `.` character in `id` attributes at all. Whilst it is valid in the HTML5 specification, it leads to confusing cases such as this.

Comment: +1 very quick and correct .

Comment: You are definitely right. Anyway, I think that the OP should not use dots in IDs anyway.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I agree completely, however they are valid in the HTML5 spec.